# Two way binding between UISearch bar text and view model property in IOS RxSwift

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I have the following code to set up binding.

```
viewModel.searchTerm
            .bind(to: searchBar.rx.text)
        .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Basically I am looking at setting up two way binding between view model property "searchTerm" and the text property of UISearchBar.

The view model property has been defined as below in the viewModel:

```
var searchTerm = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
```

This seems to be a one way binding and I do not see the view model property getting updated when user enters a text in the UISearchBar.

How should I modify this to set up two way binding?

Answer (score -1):

The code you have goes from the view model to the UI element. All you need to do is add code that goes from the element to the view model.

```
searchBar.rx.text
    .bind(to: viewModel.searchTerm)
    .dispose(by: disposeBag)
```

This works because a UI element does not emit a value when programmatically changed, only when changed by the user.

That said, I don't recommend two-way bindings. You should maintain a unidirectional data flow as much as possible.